# Passing parameters inside if-else

Tags: java, user-input

I have been through the forum numerous times, found a few answers, very helpful.  I am new to Java so be gentle.  By basic issue is I have two classes a Main and a method container.  I need to take commandline input from the user that will ask the user to set the size of an array. The user can then set each element in the array to a specific value, it must be there option to set those values, i.e, enter 2.  Then further options include getting min, max, average etc...

What I am struggling with is the code works until I do the checking of the user input, either using if-else or switch as each code block does not see the variable values that were create. For example, setting the array size parameter does not get passed into the method that sets the values of each element.  Any suggestions would be great.  Here is the code:

```
public class MyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        fc program= new fc();
        program.commandline();

    }

}
```

Method container below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fc {
    int command;

public void commandline() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int command; 
    System.out.print("Enter command>");
    command = scan.nextInt();
    while (command!=9)
    {
        if(command==1){  //set the array size

            int arraySize=getArraySize();

        }else if (command==2){  //enter values for the array

               int[]arrValues=setArrayValues(arraySize);

            }else if (command==3){

                int [] theNumbers=arrayPrint(arrValues);
                arrayPrint(arrValues);

            }else if (command==4){
                sumArray(arrValues);
                System.out.println("The sum of the array is " );

            }else if (command==5){
                minArray(arrValues);
            }else if (command==6){
                maxArray(arrValues);
            }else if (command==7){
                avgArray(arrValues);
            }else{
                printMenu();

        }


        //Read in next command
    System.out.print("Enter command>");
    command = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
public static int[] arrayPrint(int[] arrayValues) {
    System.out.println("Elem  Value");
for(int i=0;i<arrayValues.length;i++){
    System.out.printf("%s\t%d\n", i,arrayValues[i]);
}
return arrayValues;
}

public static int avgArray(int[] arrayValues) {
    int[] theNumbers1=arrayValues;
    int theSum=0;
    int avg=0;
    for (int theCounter=0; theCounter <theNumbers1.length; theCounter++)
        theSum+=theNumbers1[theCounter];
        avg=theSum/theNumbers1.length;
return avg;
}

public static int maxArray(int[] arrayValues) {
    int max = arrayValues[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++) {
        if (arrayValues[i] > max) {
            max = arrayValues[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static int minArray(int[] arrayValues) {
    int min = arrayValues[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++) {
                if (arrayValues[i] < min) {
                    min = arrayValues[i];
                }
        }
        return min;
}

public static int sumArray(int[] arrayValues) {

    int[] theNumbers1=arrayValues;
    int theSum=0;
    for (int theCounter=0; theCounter <theNumbers1.length; theCounter++)
        theSum+=theNumbers1[theCounter];
    return theSum;
}

public static int getArraySize() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the size of the array?");
    int arraySize = input.nextInt();

  return arraySize;
}

public static int[] setArrayValues(int arraySize){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[arraySize];
    System.out.println("Enter "+arraySize+ " numbers after each number press the enter key: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Set the value for index "+i);
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
return arr;
 }


public void printMenu() {
    // Print out commands to use 
    System.out.println("Type '1' to create an array of values");
    System.out.println("Type '2' to set a values in the array");
    System.out.println("Type '3' to print the array of values");
    System.out.println("Type '4' to sum an array of values");
    System.out.println("Type '5' to return the minimum number in the an array of values");
    System.out.println("Type '6' to return the maximum number in the an array of values");
    System.out.println("Type '7' to return the average of the array of values");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is all that code relevant to the specific problem you have?

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the variables *inside* the `if` blocks.

This means, in simple terms, that the program cannot know whether that variable exists, as it doesn't know whether your initialization code will ever be reached.

To make them accessible, initialize your necessary variables in the beginning and overwrite their value later on.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should be initiated outside of the if-else-block.

```
int arraySize;
int[] arrValues;
while (command!=9)
{
    if(command==1){  //set the array size

        arraySize=getArraySize();

    }else if (command==2){  //enter values for the array

           arrValues=setArrayValues(arraySize);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is *scope*.

A variable has *scope*, meaning that it is "contained" in a certain block -- the block in which it is declared. It is only visible inside that block.

So, from your code:

```
  if (command==2){  //enter values for the array
       int[] arrValues=setArrayValues(arraySize);
  }
```

Here you've done two things inside the `if` block:

- *Declared* a variable called `arrValues`
- *Assigned* a value to `arrValues`, the return value of `setArrayValues()`

But that variable can't be seen from outside that block; and inside that block you don't do anything with it. As soon as the program leaves that block, `arrValues` is forgotten, and the array assigned to it is forgotten too.

Many compilers, including the compiler behind the Eclipse editor, would give you a warning about this: "Local variable 'arrValues' is never read".

To use a variable outside the block, you have to declare it outside the block:

```
 int[] arrValues;
 if(...) {
    arrValues = setArrayValues();
 }
 doSomethingWith(arrValues);
```

Good programming is all about managing scope. It's *really useful* that you can't see all the variables everywhere -- otherwise there are just too many variables for a programmer to think about at a time. But you do need to ensure that the variable you need is visible at the point that you need it; either by declaring it in a wide enough scope, or by passing it in the parameters of method calls.

Comment: Thank you for the response it pointed me in the right direction.  I defined and initialized the parameters in the main method, called the commandline method passing the initial parameters, then the if else took over from that.